# Add node and atributes after root node to Array2XML

Tags: php, xml, nodes

I'm using Array2XML from [this link](http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-php-array-to-xml-with-attributes) and it works great!

But I need to add some nodes before the output. I need my structure to be like this:

```
<clients>
   <client>             -->Need to add
      <id>myid</id>     -->Need to add
      <name>name</name> -->Need to add
      <items>           -->Need to add
         <item>
            <title>itemtitle</title>
            <date>itemdate</date>
         </item>
      </items>
    </client>
<clients>
```

But all I can get is:

```
<clients>
   <item>
      <title>itemtitle</title>
      <date>itemdate</date>
    </item>
 <clients>
```

ROOT NODE `clients` and node `item` I can output, but how can I add node `client` and atributes `id`, `name`, and a child node `items` before the node `item`?

This is the php function wich I guess I need to make changes, but without success:

```
public static function &createXML($node_name, $arr=array()) {

    $xml = self::getXMLRoot();
    $xml->appendChild(self::convert($node_name, $arr));     

    self::$xml = null;    // clear the xml node in the class for 2nd time use.
    return $xml;
}
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work...

```
public static function &createXML($node_name, $arr=array()) {

    $xml = self::getXMLRoot();
    $clientname='client';
    $client = $xml->createElement($clientname);
    $xml->appendChild(self::convert($node_name, $arr));     

    self::$xml = null;    // clear the xml node in the class for 2nd time use.
    return $xml;
}
```

How can I add this nodes and attributes before the loop of items?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it after some head scratching...

I just need to edit to this:

```
public static function &createXML($node_name, $arr=array()) {

    $xml = self::getXMLRoot();

    $clients = $xml->createElement("clients");
    $xml->appendChild($clients);

    $client = $xml->createElement("client");
    $clients->appendChild($client);

    $id = $xml->createElement('id', 'myid');
    $client->appendChild($id);
    $name = $xml->createElement('name', 'myname');
    $client->appendChild($name);

    $client->appendChild(self::convert($node_name, $arr));      

    self::$xml = null;    // clear the xml node in the class for 2nd time use.
    return $xml;
}
```